# What are the advantages / disadvantages of a rock climbing hat made from hard plastic to one made out of carbon fiber?

Tags: safety, gear, climbing, mountaineering

What are the advantages / disadvantages of a rock climbing hat made from hard plastic to one made out of carbon fibre?

I have done a Google search already, but wanted some pointers with people who have experience.

Comment: Might you link to helmets you are considering or have ruled out?

Comment: I was really looking for an answer detailing advantages and disadvantages from specific personal experience.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have any specifics on **carbon** fibre, but from [indoorclimbing.com](http://www.indoorclimbing.com/climbing_helmets.html):

> Fiberglass and polycarbonate composite *(which would include carbon fibre)* climbing helmets absorb the
>   shock energy by breaking. The outer shell of the composite helmet
>   absorbs the energy. Plastic and nylon helmets transfer the shock to
>   the inner cradle harness. Helmets made from fiberglass or
>   polycarbonate are good choices for ice climbing.

Plastic climbing helmets are lighter than the fiberglass or polycarbonate composite helmets, they can also survive more wear and tear.

I use plastic helmets, as I mostly sport climb, and rarely use multiple pitches so I just want a helmet that is light, will take the odd bash from small stones without shattering and will be cheap to replace when I need to.

Answer (score 6):

Since a [high quality polycarbonate helmet](http://www.rei.com/product/811229/petzl-meteor-iii-climbing-helmet) is now so light, affordable and durable; the added cost and limited weight benefit of carbon fiber seems to be of limited use for all but the most weight conscious or sponsored mountaineers. Plastic fails in a much more human friendly manner without sharp edges of carbon and hard resin that it's generally superior for helmet covering and strong enough for protection from sharp objects.